# Reading System environment variable from hookscripts of codedeploy

Tags: powershell, aws-code-deploy

I am trying to read $env:CATALINA_HOME from hookscript of aws codedeploy.
But i get blank value instead of actual value. When the script run independently on machine it returns actual value.

Is there way to read system environment variable from hookscript..?

Comment: Check that your environment variable is set on system level instead of user level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CodeDeploy agent service runs as Local System user. So make sure your environment variable is set on system level. That way it will be visible to all users. -Surya